Is it possible to take back a curse?
Suppose someone cursed someone to die out of anger. But, he loves that person the most in this world. He regretted it immediately and asked God to take it back. He prayed to God to take it back. Do these curses, which are said out of anger work? Can these curses be taken back? Please help.

@Asking personal questions is not allowed on this site. But, your question is an important one. I just edited it a bit to make it sound more general.

A curse or boon, once given, cannot be undone out of respect for the person who gave it. However, it will happen in some form. If the person who is cursed realizes their mistake, or if the curse was given by mistake, there is often a softer way for it to unfold or even for it to work in the cursed person’s favor.
Everything happens as part of God’s divine plan and will (Maya). Many curses are often connected, helping to resolve or fulfill each other. Pray to Ishwara/God and do good karm.
Chapter 18, Verse 61:
"Ishvarah sarva-bhutanam hriddeshe 'rjuna tishthati,
Bhramayan sarva-bhutani yantrarudhani mayaya."

Curse is a curse which can't be rolled back but, of course, modifiable.

In the Mahabharata, Urvashi cursed Arjuna to live as a eunuch for the
rest of his life after he rejected her romantic advances. However, at
the request of Lord Indra, Urvashi reduced the curse to one year.

Arjuna used the curse to his advantage during his incognito exile period. He took on the identity of Brihanala, a eunuch who was skilled in dance and music. He became a teacher to Princess Utara of Matsia.
Conclusion:
A curse can't be taken back, but you keep praying God for forgiveness.

In  Ramayan Ahalya was cursed by Gouthama sage to get Shaap vimochana/ release  from a touch of Rama's feet in a later avatar. Also Indra got a concession, his malformed appearance is not visible to all.

@Narasimham, the Padma Purana tells that as Indra attempts to flee in the form of a cat, Gautama curses him to lose his genitals and to bear a thousand vaginas on his body. But the idea of my post was about "modifiable curse", so I chose Urvashi's curse from Mahabharatam.
